# unable to print beyond 975th prime no. using Sieve of eratosthenes

Tags: java

Here the code prints the first N prime no.s 
I allocated memory for 50000 numbers as i needed first 5000 prime number 
i.e 5000th prime no. is 48611.

But the program prints the prime numbers only upto 975th prime number not beyond that.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;



public class exp {

 private int size;
 private boolean[] arr;
 public exp(int a){
    size = a;
    arr = new boolean[size];
 }
 public void initialize(){
    for(int i=2;i<size;++i)
        arr[i] = true;

    arr[0] = arr[1] = false;
 } 

 public void precompute(){  // this function implements sieve technique
     int i=2;
     while(i<size){
        if(arr[i]){
            for(int j=2*i; j<size; j=j+i)
                arr[j] = false;
        }
        i++;
    }
 } 
 public String printX(int as){
    int counter = 0;
    String ans="",b = " ";
    for(int i=0; i<size ; ++i){
        if(arr[i]){
            ans += String.valueOf(i) + b;
            counter++;
        }
        if(counter == as)
            break;
    }
    return ans;
 }
 public static void main(String[] args) throws NumberFormatException, IOException {


    exp e = new exp(50000);
    e.initialize();
    e.precompute();

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)); 
    int t = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    int N;
    for(int i=0;i<t;++i){
        N = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        if(N == 1)
            System.out.println("1");
        else
            System.out.println(e.printX(N));
    }
 }

 }
```

Trying to print more than 975 prime no.s giving blank line in eclipse.
So what is the issue here?
IS the issue related to eclipse?

Comment: It's "Eratosthenes".  (Spell it right and Google will find all sorts of references.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be an Eclipse limitation.  The problem is with Eclipse, not with your code.  I've run your code from the command-line and it quite happily prints out 5000 primes.  I can also verify that your program prints 975 primes when run from Eclipse but a blank line when asked to print 976.  I can't say why Eclipse prints a blank line - perhaps there's some internal limitation inside the Eclipse console window that you hit once you ask it to display a line that's too long.

The simplest way to get around this is to add newlines every so often into the string being generated by `printX`.  That stops lines from getting too long.  For example, to add newlines after every 20 prime numbers, add the lines

```
            if (counter % 20 == 0) {
                ans += "\n";
            }
```

immediately after the `counter++` line.

---

Incidentally, building up a string by concatenation (i.e. using `+` and `+=`) in a loop is quite inefficient.  The problem is that every time you add a pair of strings this way, Java has to copy both strings into a new string.  As an exercise, I recommend replacing the string concatenation in this method with a [StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) instead.

Comment: Thanks Luke, I totally forgot about StringBuilder